# Why do I get the elem is not defined error if element is defined?

Tags: javascript

I have defined elements, but when I try to output anything other than the first item in the list, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: item1 is not defined`.

I have defined the variable.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
let itemOne = `<h2>Item One</h2>`;
let itemTwo = `<h2>Item Two</h2>`;
let itemThree = `<h2>Item Three</h2>`;

item1.innerHTML = itemOne;

item2.innerHTML = itemTwo;

item3.innerHTML = itemThree;
```

```html
<div id="item2"></div>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = itemOne;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `if` conditions to check if the elements exist before you try to access them.

```js
let itemOne = `<h2>Item One</h2>`;
let itemTwo = `<h2>Item Two</h2>`;
let itemThree = `<h2>Item Three</h2>`;

if (typeof(item1) !== 'undefined') item1.innerHTML = itemOne;

if (typeof(item2) !== 'undefined') item2.innerHTML = itemTwo;

if (typeof(item3) !== 'undefined') item3.innerHTML = itemThree;
```

```html
<div id="item2"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to display all the element. This is a single script that contains several elements. The script is called on every page of my site. But, I am not going to display all the elements on every page. On page one, I might display itemOne and itemThree. On page 2, I'll display itemTwo.

Comment: @JaredNewnam If there a no elements with id `item1` it's undefined in your code. You can't access `innerHTML` of undefined. You could add guards. I added some guards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem item1, item2 not found, we need to create the element, before setted it:

```js
let itemOne = `<h2>Item One</h2>`;
let itemTwo = `<h2>Item Two</h2>`;
let itemThree = `<h2>Item Three</h2>`;

document.querySelector('#item1').innerHTML = itemOne;
document.querySelector('#item2').innerHTML = itemTwo;
document.querySelector('#item3').innerHTML = itemThree;
```

```html
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item2"></div>
<div id="item3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the element first by id for example.

To prevent the error message, check if you have the element first.

```js
let itemTwo = `<h2>Item Two</h2>`;

let item2 = document.getElementById("item2");
if (item2) {
  item2.innerHTML = itemTwo;
}
```

```html
<div id="item2"></div>
```